# Docker phoenix with ssl on port 443 is not receiving anything

Tags: docker, ssl, https, elixir, phoenix-framework

Hey there fellow devs,

For the love of everything, I can't seem to get this to work... I have a docker container with a phoenix app running in there. It's hosted on a subdomain "sub.example.com" and I need to serve it with https.

So I got myself a wildcard SSL certificate, installed it, configured the production file and exposed 80 and 443 ports of the docker container.

Tried it out and port 80 works fine, but 443 is always returning a "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET". The logs is showing nothing on 443, but 80 works fine.

Been trying for awhile now, and now i need your help. Any idea on whats wrong? Check the code below:

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM bitwalker/alpine-elixir-phoenix:latest

# create app folder
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# setting the port and the environment (prod = PRODUCTION!)
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

# install dependencies (production only)
RUN mix local.rebar --force
RUN mix deps.get --only prod
RUN mix compile
```

#### prod.exs

```
config :example, ExampleWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 80],
  url: [host: "sub.example.com"],
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json",
  https: [
    cipher_suite: :strong,
    otp_app: :example,
    port: 443,
    keyfile: System.get_env("SSL_KEY_PATH"),
    certfile: System.get_env("SSL_CERT_PATH"),
    cacertfile: System.get_env("SSL_CHAINED_CERT_PATH")
  ]
```

#### curl https://sub.example.com/ --verbose result:

```
*   Trying 64.225.24.82...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sub.example.com (64.225.24.82) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to sub.example.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to sub.example.com:443
```

EDIT:
I am setting the ENV variables within the container manually. For example in bash:

```
SSL_KEY_PATH=path/example.key SSL_CERT_PATH=path/example.crt SSL_CHAINED_CERT_PATH=path/example_chained.crt MIX_ENV=prod mix phx.server
```

Comment: What version of Phoenix are you using?  And where are you setting your ENV vars (`SSL_KEY_PATH`, `SSL_CERT_PATH`, and `SSL_CHAINED_CERT_PATH`)?

Comment: What does your `docker run` command look like? Are you properly mapping your EXPOSEd ports to ports on the host? And you have you tried setting the [runtime config](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#module-runtime-configuration) for the `url` to also include `scheme` and `port`?

Comment: @Everett I am currently using `phoenix 1.4.13`. And I am setting the ENV vars at launch. My command looks like: `SSL_KEY=path/to/it SSL_CERT=path/to/it mix phx.server`.

Comment: @jamesvl My docker run command is `docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 443:443 --entrypoint=bash --name example-app example:1.0`. And I have tried setting the `scheme` and `port` as well. But to no success :(. I've been looking around and it seems maybe I have to use a proxy server like nginx or something?

Comment: When you run `mix phx.server`, are you running that from your host OS, or are you specifying that in an `ENTRYPOINT` somewhere in your Dockerfile?  Because I'm not seeing where your Docker container is getting those ENV values...

Comment: I am running it from the host OS and the ENV variables do get read.

Comment: I see the same issues as Everett - your Dockerfile doesn't define an ENTRYPOINT or a CMD; just as importantly, it doesn't define the MIX_ENV, so all of your compiling and (however you finally run the Phoenix server) is probably all being done with the `dev.exs` which usually has https turned off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching, trial and errors and sparring with other developers. I've solved the problem using a proxy server with nginx. Here are the configs that made it all happen!

phoenix - prod.exs

```
config :example, ExampleWeb.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 5000],
  url: [host: "sub.example.com", port: 5000]
```

nginx config

```
upstream phoenix {
  server 0.0.0.0:5000;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

server {
  server_name sub.example.com;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_chained.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.pem;

  large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

  location ~ live/websocket {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Origin '';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
    break;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000;
    break;
  }
}
```

Further discussion found here:

https://elixirforum.com/t/phoenix-app-in-docker-with-ssl-not-receiving-anything-on-port-443/31229

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile doesn't specify the `MIX_ENV`, so is probably building and running with the default of `MIX_ENV=dev`.

It also doesn't specify the command used to run the actual application, usually `mix phx.server` locally.

Here's a sample Dockerfile I've used to run an app locally; this is *not* optimized for size or build speed, and should not be used in production (do a full mix release for that), but in case it helps:

```
FROM elixir:1.10.1-alpine AS dev_img

# Environment
ENV MIX_ENV prod
ENV PORT 4000
ENV SSL_PORT 4001

# Install required system dependencies
RUN apk update; \
  apk upgrade --no-cache; \
  apk add --no-cache libsodium libsodium-dev nodejs npm curl git inotify-tools build-base; \
  mix local.rebar --force; \
  mix local.hex --force

WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .

RUN mix do deps.get, compile

RUN cd assets; \
  npm ci; \
  cd ..

ENV PG_DB_PORT 5432
ENV PG_DB_HOST db-container-name
ENV SSL_KEY_PATH
ENV OTHER_VARS

CMD ["mix", "phx.server"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am settings the ENV variables manually within the container with `MIX_ENV=prop SSL_PATH=example ETC=example mix phx.server`